# C - returning string

Tags: c

Can you guys help me understand why my function does not allow me to return a string. I have reviewed some code on this site, and I can't seem to get it to work. Replies to other questions have suggested that people define the function as:

```
const char * stringToRetrun(){ /*do some work*/ return string; }
```

However when I try and follow the same format my compiler spits out a whole bunch of invalid type errors/warning.

I have posted my question below:

```
char * printMenu()
{   
    char message[100] = "Select an option from below:\n";
    strcat(message, "(1) List all files on server\n");
    strcat(message, "(2) Retrieve file from server\n");
    strcat(message, "(3) Retrieve all files from server\n");
    strcat(message, "(4) Close connection\n");
    strcat(message, "Enter your selection:\n");

    return message;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: think about the scope of message

Comment: Local address can not be used in the scope of the higher-level.   
But string literals can be returned by connecting as follows.
`const char *MenuString(){   
        const char *message = "Select an option from below:\n"
        "(1) List all files on server\n"
        "(2) Retrieve file from server\n"
        "(3) Retrieve all files from server\n"
        "(4) Close connection\n"
        "Enter your selection:\n";
    
        return message;
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storage for `message` does not exist past the end of the `printMenu()` function (because it is a local array). So you cannot simply `return message` and then be able to access the string later. This is *undefined behaviour* and is incorrect.

Strings are awkward to handle in C. You can either:

1. Allocate space in the caller for the string, and have the function copy the data into that space.
2. Have the function allocate new space and return a pointer, requiring the caller to clean up the allocated space.

Comment: Third approach is to use `static char message[100];`, although that has its own set of drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a 2 major issues here:
1. The variable message is a local array and hence created on the stack. When the function returns, it returns the pointer to an address on the stack which has already been rolled back.

2. You have an array of size 100 and you have concatenated more than 100 characters, in effect corrupting the stacK